# Null Reference Exception was Unhandled

Tags: vb.net, exception, reference, null

This is a very simple code. I am just beginning to use vb. Im making a game where you reorder the shuffled numbers into the correct order. You try to solve the puzzle in the least amount of time and least amount of clicks, and the next time you play, you try to get a lower score (or beat that record). You have sixteen buttons (4x4) and fifteen numbers. There is a checkbutton function to see if the puzzle is solved Every time I debug the program, it highlights the Clicks and FinalTime and says Null Reference Exception was Unhandled. Heres some of the code.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim Clicks As Integer = 0  'The variable that counts the number of times you clicked
Dim Time As Integer 'The vairable that holds the time
Dim TimeMin As Integer 'The variable that holds the minutes
Dim TimeSec As Integer  'The variable that holds the seconds
Dim FinalTime As String 'The variable that holds the final time (minutes and seconds)
Dim lngArray() As String = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", ""} {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", ""}    
Dim NumArray() As Integer
Dim NumArray1() As String

Private Sub CheckButton(ByRef Butt1 As Button, ByRef Butt2 As Button)
    If Butt2.Text = "" Then 'Checks if the button around the clicked number is empty "" It's the location of the empty square that you want the number in Butt1 to move to.
        Butt2.Text = Butt1.Text 'If it is, the value from Butt2 will "copy and paste" into Butt1
        Butt1.Text = "" 'Butt1 will keep the value and the value in Butt2 will clear "" 
        Clicks += 1 'Incrementing Each click by only 1. It's a counter. In addition, the code above only allows the click to increment by 1 if the number has moved. If you just click on a number that can't move, the click would not count.
    End If
    If Clicks > 1 Then
        lblTotal.Text = Clicks & " Clicks" 'Shows the total amount of clicks when it is greater than one
    Else
        lblTotal.Text = Clicks & " Click" 'Shows the total amount of clicks when it is one
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckSolved() 'A private sub that checks if the puzzle is solved ,restarts the count, and stops the time
    Dim strName As String = "" 'The variable that has the string of the winners name
    If Me.Button1.Text = "1" And Me.Button2.Text = "2" And Me.Button3.Text = "3" And Me.Button4.Text = "4" And Me.Button5.Text = "5" And Me.Button6.Text = "6" And Me.Button7.Text = "7" And Me.Button8.Text = "8" And Me.Button9.Text = "9" And Me.Button10.Text = "10" And Me.Button11.Text = "11" And Me.Button12.Text = "12" And Me.Button13.Text = "13" And Me.Button14.Text = "14" And Me.Button15.Text = "15" Then 'Checks if the numbers are in the correct buttons
        Timer1.Enabled = False 'Stops the time
        strName = InputBox("What is your name", "Name of winner") 'Get's the winners name 
        MessageBox.Show("In " & FinalTime & " , you solved the puzzle in " & Me.Clicks & " clicks! Congratulations " & strName) 'Messagebox showing how many times you clicked to solve the puzzle. It gets the name you typed into the inputbox (strname) and displays it
        Call Restart() 'Shuffles the buttons and restarts the game when you win
        Call Record(NumArray, NumArray1)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Record(ByVal NumArray() As Integer, ByVal NumArray1() As String)
    'Make timemin array and then make time array. Then make click array
    For i As Integer = 0 To 1000 
        NumArray(i) = Clicks 'This is where the Null Reference error occured
        i = +1
        Array.Sort(NumArray) 'sorting the array values from least to greatest
    Next i

    lblRecordClicks.Text = NumArray(0) & " Clicks" 'displaying the lowest number of clicks in the label
    For k As Integer = 0 To 1000 'Making an  integer that captures 1000 values
        NumArray1(k) = FinalTime 'This is where the Null Reference error occured
        k = +1
        Array.Sort(NumArray1) 'sorting the array values from least to greatest
    Next k

    lblRecordTime.Text = NumArray1(0) 'displaying the lowest time in the label
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Call Times()
End Sub

Private Sub Shuffle(ByVal lngArray As Object) 'Shuffles the values of the Array 
    Dim i As Long
    Dim iMin As Long
    Dim iMax As Long
    Dim lngReplace As Long
    Dim varSwap As Object
    iMin = LBound(lngArray)
    iMax = UBound(lngArray)
    For i = iMax To iMin + 1 Step -1
        lngReplace = Int((i - iMin + 1) * Rnd() + iMin)
        varSwap = lngArray(i)
        lngArray(i) = lngArray(lngReplace)
        lngArray(lngReplace) = varSwap
    Next
    Button1.Text = lngArray(0)
    Button2.Text = lngArray(1)
    Button3.Text = lngArray(2)
    Button4.Text = lngArray(3)
    Button5.Text = lngArray(4)
    Button6.Text = lngArray(5)
    Button7.Text = lngArray(6)
    Button8.Text = lngArray(7)
    Button9.Text = lngArray(8)
    Button10.Text = lngArray(9)
    Button11.Text = lngArray(10)
    Button12.Text = lngArray(11)
    Button13.Text = lngArray(12)
    Button14.Text = lngArray(13)
    Button15.Text = lngArray(14)
    Button16.Text = lngArray(15)
End Sub

Private Sub RestartToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RestartToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Call Restart()
    Call Me.btnStart_Click(sender, e) 'Call the button click to enable all buttons
End Sub
Private Sub Times()
    Time = Time + 1 'Increase the time by 1 second every interval
    TimeSec = TimeSec + 1 'Increase the time by 1 second every interval
    TimeMin = Convert.ToInt32(TimeSec \ 60) 'Takes the whole number of the amount of seconds divided by 60 and leaves out the remainder
    If Time >= 60 Then
        Time = 0
    End If
    'If the seconds pass 59 (and they do), it restarts to 0
    FinalTime = TimeMin & " min " & Time & " seconds" 'Final time is the string displayed showing the final time
    lblTime.Text = FinalTime 'The label displays the final time
End Sub
Private Sub Restart()
    Time = 0 'Resets the time
    Clicks = 0 'Resets the amount of clicks
    lblTotal.Text = "" 'Clears the label
    lblCheat.Visible = False
    lblTotal.Visible = True
    lblClicks.Visible = True
    lblQuote.Visible = True
    lblRecordClicks.Visible = True
    lblRecordTime.Visible = True
    'If the user cheated and hit the solve button and wants to restart and solve the puzzle on their own, then he can. Turning these label settings to true allows you to see them again
    Call Shuffle(lngArray) 'Shuffles the numbers
    Timer1.Enabled = True 'Continues the time when it resets to 0

End Sub

Public Sub RefreshEverythingToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RefreshEverythingToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = False 'Pauses the timer
    If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to restart everything?", "Restart Game", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Time = 0
        TimeSec = 0
        'Resets the time
        Clicks = 0 'Resets the amount of clicks
        lblTotal.Text = "" 'Clears the label
        lblRecordClicks.Text = "" 'Resets the record click
        lblRecordTime.Text = "" 'Resets the record time
    End If
    Call Shuffle(lngArray) 'Shuffles the numbers
    Timer1.Enabled = True 'Continues the timer if no is selected
    ReDim NumArray(1000) 'Clears the array data that was captured
    ReDim NumArray1(1000) 'Clears the array data that was captured
End Sub

End Class
```

If you do decide to help (and I HOPE you do) could you try to avoid using "computer" talk and try to "dumb it down for me". Like I said before, I am new at this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Which line does the exception happen in?

Comment: Theres a comment on the lines where this happenens... 'This is where the Null Reference error occured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to save the values to an array. When you define an array like `Dim NumArray() As Integer` there are no bounds set for the array (the array is basically `Nothing`) and if you then try to access an array item you encounter the Null reference exception.
You only set the array bounds in `Public Sub RefreshEverythingToolStripMenuItem_Click`. Now I don't know all of your code but if the game is started without the user specifically clicking this button then your array will be Nothing.
You have to make sure that the array bounds are always set before a game is started.

You could also look into more abstract array-like types in .NET. For example you could try a list. A List is practically an array with arbitrary bounds. You define the List with a specific type using the Of keyword and you can then add items to it with the lists Add method, remove items, sort the list etc.

Define as a global variable:

```
Dim FinalTimes as New List(Of Integer)
Dim FinalClicks as New List(Of Integer)
```

Make sure you use the New keyword here. This means that a new object of class List will be created. Otherwise you would encounter Null Reference Exceptions on the lines below again.
When the user solves the puzzle you then do:

```
FinalTimes.Add(FinalTime)
FinalClicks.Add(Clicks)
FinalTimes.Sort
FinalClicks.Sort
```

This will basically increase the length of the list by one, write the FinalTime/Clicks value into the last item and then resort both lists. Ideas: For a highscore you might want to connect FinalTime, Clicks and Player Name into a structure and use the IComparer Interface to let the user sort the high score list by name/Time/Clicks.

- Jens

PS: Before I forget: The For loops in which the exception occured in your code make no real sense. First problem is that in their current forms they would be infinite loops because you always set i to 1 in the loop while the loop ends when i=1000 (which would never happen, obviously). I think you meant `i=i+1` or shorter `i += 1` there. But they still make little sense. I tried it out to see what happens exactly (which is not obvious :-)) and half of your high score is overwritten by the new value etc. I think the above method will be easier. :-)

Comment: How would you display the sorted FinalTimes and FinalClicks in a label? I didn't exactly understand your explanation of the paragraph underneath the code where you sorted the variables FinalClicks and Final Times.

Comment: `FinalTimes.Sort` would just sort the values in the list, it does not display them. In order to display the values you can make your own `Function ListToString(ByVal l as List(Of Integer)) as String`. In there: `Dim res as string = ""`, then `For each i as integer in l`, then `res &= i.tostring`, then `Next`, then `Return res`, `End Function`. In your code: `lblTimes.Text = ListToString(FinalTimes)`